# How do I sync content types, taxonomy, menus among in a drupal multisite environment?

Tags: drupal-7

I have a drupal 7 multisite setup. For example I have site1.com and site2.com. I manually created a new content type for site1.com (let's call it 'books') and would like to sync/share it with site2.com without having to manually recreate 'books' in site2.com. How could I achieve this? Thank you very much for any feedback.

Answer (score -1):

Use [Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features), which exports your content type to code so you can easily export it between sites.